# DotNetCore 3.1 Web Api empty object response

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When returning a class instance with public properties, an empty JSON object { } is returned.
However, if I return a dynamic object, the expected response is returned.
I'm using VS2019 with the latest patches.
Steps to reproduce, create a ASP.NET Core Web API project and select .NET Core 3.1 (LTS) as the framework.
Replace the contents of WeatherForecastController.cs with what I have included below and run the application.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class JsonResponse
    {
        public string Challenge;

        public int Ttl;
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            JsonResponse rsp = new JsonResponse { Challenge = "challenge", Ttl = 1 };
            return Ok(rsp); // returns { }
            //return Ok(new { Challenge = "challenge", Ttl = 1 }); // returns { challenge: "challenge", ttl: 1 }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: if you migrating from 2 > 3.1 you have to add services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(); in startup.cs > ConfigureServices method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to modify your `JsonResponse` class to make property contains declarations for a `get` and `set` accessor, like below.

```
public class JsonResponse
{
    public string Challenge { get; set; }

    public int Ttl { get; set; }
}
```

And as mentioned in this doc about ["Serialization behavior"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#serialization-behavior), fields are ignored by default.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is required for a public property (was not a problem in Core 2.1) but that did the trick.